# Find the rows in which the (aboslute) value is bigger than

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like:

| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 10 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 0 | 3 | 4 |
| -10 | 3 | 4 |

Now observing the first column (labeled 'one') I would like to find the rows where the value is bigger than say 9. (in this case it would be the fourth )

Ideally, I also would like to find the rows where the absolute value of the value is bigger than say 9 (so that would be fourth and seventh)

How can I do this? (So far I only covert the columns into series and even into series of truths and false but my problem is that my dataframe is huge and I cannot visually inspect it. I need to get the row numbers automatically

Comment: Can you share your expected output? Are you looking for just the row numbers? Also, you can share what you have attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can apply `abs` and compare and filter by `loc`:

```
out = df.loc[df['one'].abs() > 9]
```

output :

```
>>>
   one  two  three
3   10    3      4
6  -10    3      4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use abs() [pandas-abs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a': [1, 4, -6, 3, 7],
'b': [2, 3, 5, 3, 1],
'c': [4, 2, 7, 1, 3]
})

df[df.a.abs() > 5]
```

returns two rows 2, 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
row = {} 
for column in df:
    row_temp = {}
    index = df.loc[df[column].abs()>=9].index
    row.update({column:list(index)})
```

Comment: I don't know exactly to what question this is the answer, but surely not to the current question. It seems that your are trying to build a dictionary of columns associated to the list of indexes in which this column values is over 9. That is not what was asked for.

Comment: The question was vague, I didn't know what output he/she wants. That's why I create to overcome most of the possibilities.